# Core Data: Fetch all children in a 1 to many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have 1-many relationship and I am successfully putting data into it. The problem is that I am not able to fetch it out via the relationship attribute.

My ADD Code:

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CBICoreDataController sharedInstance] masterManagedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *orders = [NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UnsyncedOrders"
                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
   [orders setValue:[dictionary valueForKey:@"specialInstructions"] forKey:@"specialInstructions"];
[orders setValue:[dictionary valueForKey:@"poNumber"] forKey:@"poNumber"];
[orders setValue:[dictionary valueForKey:@"specialInstructions"] forKey:@"specialInstructions"];
 [orders setValue:[dictionary valueForKey:@"deliveryDate"] forKey:@"deliveryDate"];
 [orders setValue:[dictionary valueForKey:@"account"] forKey:@"account"];

NSMutableSet *muteSet=[orders mutableSetValueForKey:@"items"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in [dictionary valueForKey:@"items"]) {
    NSManagedObject *items = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UnsyncedOrderItems"
                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [items setValue:[dict valueForKey:@"arraykey"] forKey:@"arrayKey"];
     //Other Sets Here

    [muteSet addObject:items];
}

[orders setValue:muteSet forKey:@"items"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving in writeToMenuCostingDetailsTable: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

What I have for the fetch now but it does not work:

```
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"arrayKey" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSEntityDescription *parent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UnsyncedOrders"
            inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSEntityDescription *child = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UnsyncedOrderItems"
            inManagedObjectContext:context];


[fetchRequest setEntity:child];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orders == %@", parent];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

NSError *error;

[aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [aFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `orders` relationship relates to a **specific instance of `UnsyncedOrders`**. However when you try to perform a fetch, you do this:

```
NSEntityDescription *parent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UnsyncedOrders"
        inManagedObjectContext:context];
[...]
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orders == %@", parent];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

You're trying to fetch instances where the `orders` relationship points to the `UnsyncedOrders` entity itself, not those that relate to a specific instance of `UnsyncedOrders`. That's always going to fail. In fact there's a good chance that if you were checking the result of `performFetch:` that it's returning `NO` and providing you with some sort of error describing the problem.

If you want to fetch the `UnsyncedOrderItems` that relate to a specific instance of `UnsyncedOrders`, you need to use a predicate that refers to a specific instance. However, if you already have that instance, you don't need to fetch-- just ask the `UnsyncedOrders` instance for the value of its `items` relationship.

Comment: I took your base code and inputted it but now I get I took your base code and added on but now I get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
*** First throw call stack

Comment: NSEntityDescription *parent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UnsyncedOrders"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"items == %@", parent];

Comment: [request setPredicate:predicate];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"arrayKey" ascending:YES];
        [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    [request setEntity:parent];
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;

Comment: I was quoting from your code. You should not copy code from my answer, because that code came directly from your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I ended up using:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CBICoreDataController sharedInstance] masterManagedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UnsyncedOrders"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error = nil;
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (UnsyncedOrders *info in fetchedObjects) {
    [mutableArray addObject:info.items];
}
```